# PHP login not redirecting to protected page

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a login page for an administrative backend. For some reason my form is not redirecting me to the protected index page. I feel like I am missing something super simple.

Login Form

```html
<?php 
include_once '../db/db_connect.php'; 
include_once '../db/functions.php'; 

sec_session_start(); 
if (login_check($mysqli)==true) { 
 $logged='in' ; 
} else { 
 $logged='out' ; 
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">

 <title>Login | Duplin County Employee Portal</title>

 <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
 <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
 <link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Custom CSS -->
 <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Custom Fonts -->
 <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
 <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
 <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/sha512.js"></script>
 <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <?php if (isset($_GET[ 'error'])) { echo '<p class="error">Error Logging In!</p>'; } ?>
      <form action="../db/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
       <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
         <input class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" type="text" name="username" autofocus/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
         <label>
          <input name="remember_me" id="remember_me" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me" checked="checked">Remember Me
         </label>
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="button" value="Login" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.username, this.form.password);" />
       </fieldset>
      </form>

      <?php if (login_check($mysqli)==true) { echo '<p>Currently logged ' . $logged . ' as ' . htmlentities($_SESSION[ 'username']) . '.</p>'; echo '<p>Do you want to change user? <a href="includes/logout.php">Log out</a>.</p>'; } else { echo '<p>Currently logged ' . $logged . '.</p>'; echo "<p>If you don't have a login, please <a href='register.php'>register</a></p>"; } ?>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>



 <!-- jQuery -->
 <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
 <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
 <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
 <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Process Login PHP

```html
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
 
sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.
 
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.
 
    if (login($username, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login success 
        header('Location: ../pages/index.php');
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

Secure Session Function

```html
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

Login Functions

```html
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
    // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt 
        FROM users
       WHERE username = ?
        LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);  // Bind "$username" to parameter.
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();
 
        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($users_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
        $stmt->fetch();
 
        // hash the password with the unique salt.
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
            // from too many login attempts 
 
            if (checkbrute($users_id, $mysqli) == true) {
                // Account is locked 
                // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
                return false;
            } else {
                // Check if the password in the database matches
                // the password the user submitted.
                if ($db_password == $password) {
                    // Password is correct!
                    // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                    $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $users_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $users_id);
                    $_SESSION['users_id'] = $users_id;
                    // XSS protection as we might print this value
                    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                                "", 
                                                                $username);
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                              $password . $user_browser);
                    // Login successful.
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Password is not correct
                    // We record this attempt in the database
                    $now = time();
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                    VALUES ('$users_id', '$now')");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I am positive that the issue is in one of these three files. Any help you can give me would be amazing.

Comment: Is the sec_session_start function setting any cookies?

Comment: Problem is probably in your homemade `sec_session_start()` and `login_check()` and `login()` functions. By the way, in English 'logged' and 'logged in` do not mean the same thing. 'Logged in' means authenticated; 'logged' means stored in a log file.

Comment: This won't solve your issue, but as a side note, you should add `exit;` after your `header(..)` functions; otherwise, the rest of your code will be run before it redirects.

Comment: The sec_session_start function is setting cookies. I added it to the post for you to see.

Comment: @developerwjk do you have any suggestions as to what it could be within one of the functions you mentioned? Right not I'm not concerned over the semantics of the $logged statement. That portion is working fine.